# How do I check if two LocalDates are in the past?

Tags: java, localdate

I am currently programming error avoidance. So I have two LocalDates: from and until and I want to check if one of them is in the past.

This is my method. But somewhere there seems to be an error, because if I select a LocalDate for "from" which is in the past, I get a false back.

```
    private static boolean isPast(LocalDate from, LocalDate until) {
        if (LocalDate.now().isAfter(from) || LocalDate.now().isAfter(until)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the input, what is the expected vs. actual output? Think about the statements you actually wrote: "now is after from or now is after until" - is that what you want?

Comment: write some unit test for it, and you will kill the bug in no time

Comment: Is `from` always before `until`?

Comment: Not certain what the problem is.  I tried every combination and got the expected results.

Comment: It would also cleaner if you call LocalDate.now() only once: LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); if (now.isAfter(from) || now.isAfter(until)) ... Although it is not related to the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively you could write:

```
private static boolean atLeastOneInThePast(LocalDate from, LocalDate until) {
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    return today.isAfter(from) || today.isAfter(until);
}
```

Which is 23:59 consistent. And allows an easy debugging of `today`.

Your code seems fine, if `from` is yesterday. So only your system clock, `LocalDate.now()`, may be off.

Comment: Somehow my system clock was wrong. Thanks alot for the clean code :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the test.  You want to check if one of your dates is in the past. Your method works.

```
        LocalDate a = LocalDate.of(2010, 1, 10); // past
        LocalDate b = LocalDate.of(2030, 2, 10); // future
        System.out.println(isPast(a,b)); // prints true


         a = LocalDate.of(2030, 1, 10); // future
         b = LocalDate.of(2010, 2, 10); // past
         System.out.println(isPast(a,b)); // prints true

         a = LocalDate.of(2030, 1, 10);  // future
         b = LocalDate.of(2030, 2, 20);  // future
         System.out.println(isPast(a,b)); // prints false

         a = LocalDate.of(2010, 1, 10); // past
         b = LocalDate.of(2010, 2, 10); // past

         System.out.println(isPast(a,b)); // prints true
```

There may be granularity or timezone problems depending on how you specified the dates.

Answer (score 0):

It's more clean to use javax annotation `@Future` and `@Past` on your bean date fields.

See: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html